# Expanding 'more' link in quora

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to follow the instructions here:

https://www.quora.com/Can-you-download-all-Quora-answers-from-one-person

to get all of the answers of a user.

The script provided is:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() { 
window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);}, 100);
clearInterval(interval);
```

which works so far.

However when I type:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.more_link')].map( e => e.click() );
```

to try to expand the 'more links' of expanded answers but it's not working.

A sample case is: https://www.quora.com/profile/Mehul-Mohan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for items on the page with class `more_link`, but it looks like Quora changed the class name from `more_link` to `ui_qtext_more_link` at some point between now and the time that answer was posted.

The following should work with the page in its current state:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.ui_qtext_more_link')].map( e => e.click() );
```